# How to represent clang AST in JSON format?

Tags: json, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

`clang-check -ast-dump -ast-dump-filter=<function_name> main.c` gives a AST (only a function declaration) of the particular code.

How can we represent generated AST in JSON format?

PS: I Want AST for function declaration only.

Answer (score 10):

Call `clang` with the `-ast-dump=json` argument.

This was implemented only recently (May 2019) so you need an up-to-date version of Clang.

See https://reviews.llvm.org/D60910 for details.

There's also a library to export more lower-level information available via libTooling at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-clang-plugins

*Update in 2022:* The full command line is now `clang -Xclang -ast-dump=json -fsyntax-only <file>` since the `clang` command is now a compilation driver, not just the compiler itself.

Comment: this `-ast-dump=json` is supported with `clang` but not with `clang-check`
And this is working fine for C program not C++

Comment: Using clang from 2021 and it doesn't work for me: `clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-ast-dump=json' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`

Comment: @kungfooman Answer updated for the latest version of clang.

Comment: @Jaen The updated answer works perfectly, thank you! Its funny that it generates ~400 lines from a 3 line function.

Comment: with filter: `clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -ast-dump=json -Xclang -ast-dump-filter=some_function some_source.cc`